# Integration of Laplacian of mean curvature on manifold.

Tags: riemannian-geometry, curvature, mean-curvature-flows

Assume $M$ is a n-dim convexity compact surface in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$, and $H$ is the mean curvature of $M$. How to show 
$$
\int_M \Delta H=0
$$
I get this question from the 43th page of 
*Huisken, Gerhard*, [**The volume preserving mean curvature flow**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1515/crll.1987.382.35), J. Reine Angew. Math. 382, 35-48 (1987). [ZBL0621.53007](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0621.53007).

As picture below, $\int \Delta H$ vanish. But seemly, there is not any condition making it is zero. So I guess for general convexity compact surface, we have $\int_M \Delta H=0$. But I fail to prove it.  I just know to use the definition of mean curvature to calculate it.

> [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It follows from the fact that $M$ is compact and without boundary and from the divergence theorem.

Comment: I am so stuped.

Comment: ahah don't worry! :D It happens very often to me too! Are you also studying the mean curvature flow?

Comment: Yes, but I just be a rookie. Only Huisken's The volume preserving mean curvature flow I almost finish.  Thanks.